# el resultado de un replace de mysql distinto si lo hago con php o con phpmyadmin

Tags: str-replace

Este es mi código:

```
UPDATE basedatos.tabla 
             SET columna= REPLACE (columna,'\\\\SERVER','D:xampp\\htdocs')
             WHERE id=1
```

El resultado en phpmyadmin es `D:xampp\htdocs.` Es el correcto

Y en php me escribe `\D:xampphtdocs.`
Alguien sabe por qué?

Gracias

Comment: de seguro el php te esta escapando los backslash \ ...

Answer (score 0):

Tal como dicen en los comentarios, al escribir esa consulta (como un string) debes escapar las contrabarras `\` de nuevo.

Esta es tu consulta como un string en php:

```
$consulta = "... columna= REPLACE (columna,'\\\\SERVER','D:xampp\\htdocs') ..."
```

Como en los strings php, la contrabarra se utiliza para escapar, la consulta real que llega a base de datos es:

`... columna= REPLACE (columna,'\\SERVER','D:xampp\htdocs') ...`

Pero además, la función REPLACE puede recibir strings/literales como parámetros, así que también utiliza las contrabarras para escapar comillas y otras contrabarras.

Así pues, esta SQL:

`... columna= REPLACE (columna,'\\SERVER','D:xampp\htdocs') ...`

En realidad quiere decir: Reemplaza en "columna", esto: "\SERVER" por "D:xampphtdocs"

(En el segundo parámetro la contrabarra desaparece porque solo hay una y dentro del string debería haber 2 porque las contrabarras deben escaparse)

Entonces si la columna vale `\\SERVER` y Remplazamos `\SERVER` por `D:xampphtdocs`, nos queda lo que obtienes: `\D:xampphtdocs`

Para solucionarlo, prueba escapando las contrabarras de nuevo:

```
$miconsulta = "
UPDATE basedatos.tabla 
  SET columna= REPLACE (columna,'\\\\\\\\SERVER','D:xampp\\\\htdocs')
  WHERE id=1
";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y tu tiempo.

Comment: De nada. Si te sirvió recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como válida. Un saludo.